# Limit of definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I found this problem on an old math contest:

$$\lim_{b\to1^+}\int_1^b\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(x-1)(b-x)}}.$$

I've tried substituting $u=\sqrt{x}$, but that hasn't helped much. I've also looked for ways to interpret this geometrically, since numerical estimation suggests the answer is $\pi$. I've also had the idea to try expressing the integrand as a series to get a better handle on how fast terms are growing, but I can't make that work either.

Mainly, the difficulty seems to come from the fact that the integrand is undefined at both boundaries, and that the width of the interval is also going to 0. I'm not sure how to work around either of these, but any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @SamirKhan Just wondering, from what math contest did this problem come?

Comment: I don't understand your problem since the term under the square is negative.

Comment: Wythagoras, this comes from the 2013 Mu Alpha Theta National Convention Integration Topic Test.